How @PostConstruct method can be reused in other class without duplicating the code
I have a Service class , in below code, after the bean is instantiated by Spring, the 'getRepositoryInstance' method is automatically invoked.
Inside this method, it retrieves an instance of a repository service from a factory object and assigns it to the identityRepoService variable.
In RepoService class, which has createRecord method which is calling createMapper() from Mapper class.
In Mapper class, I have to use repoService again to the get the records.
In Mapper class should I use the same postConstruct code that is in Service class?
But, when I use the same postConstruct code in Mapper class, getting null pointer for repoService.
class Service {

    @Autowired
    private RepoFactory factory;

    private RepoService repoService;

    @PostConstruct
    public void getRepositoryInstance() {
        repoService = factory.getRepositoryService();
    }

    public void create() {
        repoService.createRecord();
    }

}

@Service
@Qualifier("repoService")
class RepoService {

@Autowired
private mapper;

 createRecord(){
  mapper.createMapper();
}

@Component
class Mapper {

  createMapper(){
    repoService.getRecord();
  }
} ```


Looks like bad design that will lead to a cyclical dependency. Rather than address the NPE or the reuse of PostConstruct, try to revisit the design of your code.

Put the factory.getRepositoryService call in an @Bean method exposing the RepoService as a regular Spring bean. With that you can just do dependency injection and don't need the @PostConstruct at all.

Refactor your code. Just inject the RepoService not the RepoFactory. To make this possible just write an @Bean method that exposes the service, that way you can just inject the service where you need it.
@Configuration
public class SomeConfig {

  @Bean
  public RepoService repoService(RepoFactory factory) {
    return factory.getRepositoryService();
  }
}

Now you can just inject the service where you need it.
class Service {

    @Autowired
    private RepoService repoService;

    public void create() {
        repoService.createRecord();
    }

}

And your mapper
@Component
class Mapper {

  @Autowired
  private RepoService repoService;

}

Now there is one problem with your setup as your service depends on the Mapper and vice-versa. So you have a circular dependency here. Which is a design flaw/smell. To fix mark one of the dependencies as @Lazy which will delay the actual injection until it is needed/requested. However you are probably better of by checking your design in the first place.
Finally your RepoFactory (although not included) is strange as well as your RepoService is already marked as an @Service.

Thank you for the solution!
As I am using Qualifier("repoService") in RepoService class, injected the reposervice in service and mapper classes using Qualifier . It is working as expected.
`class Service {
@Autowired
@Qualifier("repoService")
private RepoService repoService;

}`
Should I still need to change the design?

Yes as you still have a circular dependency, this isn't solved by the @Qualifier. It works in this instance because you are using field injection. If you would make this constructor injection (the recommended way) it wouldn't work. Circular dependencies are a design smell and probably meaning your service is doing too much.
